# How to adjust image wrapping style in Apache POI

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, docx

I have to create a Word document (docx) with an image behind the text. I managed to add the image with this code:

```
XWPFParagraph p = doc.createParagraph();
XWPFRun r = p.createRun();
String imgFile = "image.png";
XWPFPicture picture = r.addPicture(new FileInputStream(imgFile), XWPFDocument.PICTURE_TYPE_PNG, imgFile, Units.pixelToEMU(855), Units.pixelToEMU(776));
```

But I can find anywhere how to send it behind the text (kinda like a background image or a watermark).

Comment: OK, Try out the code using wordMLPackage.

Comment: wordMLPackage worked fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the bellow complete code ..

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

import org.docx4j.XmlUtils;
import org.docx4j.jaxb.Context;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.packages.WordprocessingMLPackage;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.PartName;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.HeaderPart;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.WordprocessingML.ImagePngPart;
import org.docx4j.openpackaging.parts.relationships.RelationshipsPart.AddPartBehaviour;
import org.docx4j.relationships.Relationship;
import org.docx4j.wml.Hdr;
import org.docx4j.wml.ObjectFactory;
import org.docx4j.wml.SectPr;


public class Watermark
{


    static String DOCX_OUT; 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {

        // The image to add
        imageFile = new File("d:\\1\\1.png" );  

        // Save it to
        DOCX_OUT = "d:\\1\\output.docx";

        WatermarkPicture sample = new WatermarkPicture();
        sample.addWaterMark();
    }

    static ObjectFactory factory = Context.getWmlObjectFactory();
    static File imageFile; 

    private byte[] image;    
    private WordprocessingMLPackage wordMLPackage;

    public void addWaterMark() throws Exception
    {

        image = this.getImage();

        wordMLPackage = WordprocessingMLPackage
                .createPackage();

        // A watermark is defined in the headers, which are in turn set in sectPr
        wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().getContents().getBody().setSectPr(
                createSectPr() );

        File f = new File(DOCX_OUT);
        wordMLPackage.save(f);

    }

    private SectPr createSectPr() throws Exception {

        String openXML = "<w:sectPr xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\">"

                // Word adds the background image in each of 3 header parts
                + "<w:headerReference r:id=\"" + createHeaderPart("even").getId() + "\" w:type=\"even\"/>"
                + "<w:headerReference r:id=\"" + createHeaderPart("default").getId() + "\" w:type=\"default\"/>"
                + "<w:headerReference r:id=\"" + createHeaderPart("first").getId() + "\" w:type=\"first\"/>"

                // Word adds empty footer parts when you create a watermark, but its not necessary

//              + "<w:footerReference r:id=\"rId9\" w:type=\"even\"/>"
//              + "<w:footerReference r:id=\"rId10\" w:type=\"default\"/>"
//              + "<w:footerReference r:id=\"rId12\" w:type=\"first\"/>"

                + "<w:pgSz w:h=\"15840\" w:w=\"12240\"/>"
                + "<w:pgMar w:bottom=\"1440\" w:footer=\"708\" w:gutter=\"0\" w:header=\"708\" w:left=\"1440\" w:right=\"1440\" w:top=\"1440\"/>"
                + "<w:cols w:space=\"708\"/>"
                + "<w:docGrid w:linePitch=\"360\"/>"
            +"</w:sectPr>";

        return (SectPr)XmlUtils.unmarshalString(openXML);

    }

    private Relationship createHeaderPart(String nameSuffix) throws Exception {

        HeaderPart headerPart = new HeaderPart(new PartName("/word/header-" + nameSuffix + ".xml"));
        Relationship rel =  wordMLPackage.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(headerPart);

        setHdr( headerPart);

        return rel;
    }

    private void setHdr(HeaderPart headerPart) throws Exception  {

        ImagePngPart imagePart = new ImagePngPart(new PartName("/media/background.png"));
        imagePart.setBinaryData(image);
        Relationship rel = headerPart.addTargetPart(imagePart, AddPartBehaviour.REUSE_EXISTING); // the one image is shared by the 3 header parts

        String openXML = "<w:hdr mc:Ignorable=\"w14 wp14\" xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:w=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:mc=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006\" xmlns:r=\"http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships\">"
                + "<w:p>"
                    + "<w:pPr>"
                        + "<w:pStyle w:val=\"Header\"/>"
                    +"</w:pPr>"
                    + "<w:r>"
                        + "<w:rPr>"
                            + "<w:noProof/>"
                        +"</w:rPr>"
                        + "<w:pict>"
                            + "<v:shapetype coordsize=\"21600,21600\" filled=\"f\" id=\"_x0000_t75\" o:preferrelative=\"t\" o:spt=\"75\" path=\"m@4@5l@4@11@9@11@9@5xe\" stroked=\"f\">"
                                + "<v:stroke joinstyle=\"miter\"/>"
                                + "<v:formulas>"
                                    + "<v:f eqn=\"if lineDrawn pixelLineWidth 0\"/>"
                                    + "<v:f eqn=\"sum @0 1 0\"/>"
                                    + "<v:f eqn=\"sum 0 0 @1\"/>"
                                    + "<v:f eqn=\"prod @2 1 2\"/>"
                                    + "<v:f eqn=\"prod @3 21600 pixelWidth\"/>"
                                    + "<v:f eqn=\"prod @3 21600 pixelHeight\"/>"
                                    + "<v:f eqn=\"sum @0 0 1\"/>"
                                    + "<v:f eqn=\"prod @6 1 2\"/>"
                                    + "<v:f eqn=\"prod @7 21600 pixelWidth\"/>"
                                    + "<v:f eqn=\"sum @8 21600 0\"/>"
                                    + "<v:f eqn=\"prod @7 21600 pixelHeight\"/>"
                                    + "<v:f eqn=\"sum @10 21600 0\"/>"
                                +"</v:formulas>"
                                + "<v:path gradientshapeok=\"t\" o:connecttype=\"rect\" o:extrusionok=\"f\"/>"
                                + "<o:lock aspectratio=\"t\" v:ext=\"edit\"/>"
                            +"</v:shapetype>"
                            + "<v:shape id=\"WordPictureWatermark835936646\" o:allowincell=\"f\" o:spid=\"_x0000_s2050\" style=\"position:absolute;margin-left:0;margin-top:0;width:467.95pt;height:615.75pt;z-index:-251657216;mso-position-horizontal:center;mso-position-horizontal-relative:margin;mso-position-vertical:center;mso-position-vertical-relative:margin\" type=\"#_x0000_t75\">"
                                + "<v:imagedata blacklevel=\"22938f\" gain=\"19661f\" o:title=\"docx4j-logo\" r:id=\"" + rel.getId() + "\"/>"
                            +"</v:shape>"
                        +"</w:pict>"
                    +"</w:r>"
                +"</w:p>"
            +"</w:hdr>";

            Hdr hdr = (Hdr)XmlUtils.unmarshalString(openXML);

            headerPart.setJaxbElement(hdr);

        }

    private byte[] getImage() throws IOException {

        // Our utility method wants that as a byte array
        java.io.InputStream is = new java.io.FileInputStream(imageFile );
        long length = imageFile.length();    
        // You cannot create an array using a long type.
        // It needs to be an int type.
        if (length > Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
            System.out.println("File too large!!");
        }
        byte[] bytes = new byte[(int)length];
        int offset = 0;
        int numRead = 0;
        while (offset < bytes.length
               && (numRead=is.read(bytes, offset, bytes.length-offset)) >= 0) {
            offset += numRead;
        }
        // Ensure all the bytes have been read in
        if (offset < bytes.length) {
            System.out.println("Could not completely read file "+imageFile.getName());
        }
        is.close();

        return bytes;
    }


}
```

Hope this helps you!!
Thank you Happy coding !!!

Comment: I'm used to Apache. Do you think docx4java is better? All the code has been made with Apache it'd be easier not to change to docx4java...

Comment: No issue regarding docx4j .You cannot stick to one api always try updating or adding as it increases functionality as well as gives much room to open ideas and skill full programming.l

Comment: docx4j has even better and well known approached to handle docx files .You can even implement document merging  and merging of header footer with docx4j efficiently.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for all the help

Comment: If you are satisfied with the answer accept it by clicking rite mark beside answer or if at all it helped you some how give it plus vote.

Comment: Your votes or acceptance of this question helps others.